# Sharing Resources Between MAUI and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, maui, embedded-resource, resourcedictionary

I have been writing C#/WPF applications for years, but have started to experiment with some apps using MAUI.

Over time, I have gathered icons and other visual resources in to a class library which has the tags:

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<UseWpf>true</UseWpf>
```

My icons are then loaded as XAML from ResourceDictionaries depending on the application theme etc. This has been a really nice way of having a single XAML file per icon set and loading them all from a single library.

With MAUI, I first attempted to remove the -windows and UseWpf tags so I was compiling pure shared net7.0. This, of course, means that my existing WPF applications fail to find the resources using Pack notation.

I realise I could have one resource assembly for WPF and another for MAUI, but I've already created fairly mature scripts to import new icons to all the icon sets, and if there's a way of sharing a single library, that's what I'd like to do.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to share those assets via a project reference or via a nupkg? The problem is that in MAUI assets are required to have the build action set to `MauiAsset`, `MauiImage`, etc., which is then used to embed the resource and deal with platform specifics under the hood. This is fundamentally different to how WPF deals with assets. Making this compatible would require some hacks, I suppose, like setting up build configurations that output different DLLs, one being compliant with MAUI and one for WPF.

Comment: I am doubtful about getting the same source to compile into a neat dll one for each.  You'd need some serious interpretation and transformation. Probably want some way to mark parts for maui or wpf only. Feels like a project of itself.

Comment: Definitely, it won't be easy to do. Some build action, csproj and transformation magic would be required. With all that additional work, it would probably be more efficient to just manage those resources completely separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

Maui might use xaml but it's a different flavour of xaml than wpf.

A maui resource dictionary has different headings to a wpf one. You can't even share a resource dictionary file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-7.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
```

Whereas a wpf resource dictionary outer tag would be:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
           
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

If you stored your resources as xml then you could build resource dictionaries on the fly for both.

You'd have to be really careful you don't use something doesn't work in maui ( or wpf ).

Even then, you'll have complications with things like pictures. Things that work in one will not in the other.

The more I think about it the more I think this is a minefield.

I am doubtful whether this would be practical. I think porting is likely to be much more viable. If your wpf resources are fairly mature then maybe they aren't going to change much.

Comment: You'd still have the problem that in MAUI, the assets need to have the `MauiAsset` or `MauiImage`, etc. build actions to be usable in XAML and ResourceDictionary

Comment: Good point. I tend to have geometries in my resource dictionaries for as much  iconography as I can @ewerspej.

Comment: SVGs might work, if a platform specific SvgImageSource or some other loader is provided.

Comment: wpf doesn't do well with svg.  There's no in built support.

Comment: That's right, for that you'd need some kind of loader or converter. Essentially, Paths in WPF work in the same way as SVGs, don't they?

Comment: If your svg only has the one path and geometry in it, yep.  The geometry language is the same. You'd want one of the drawing things like a drawingbrush in wpf for multiple geometries with different colours.  Conceptually you could do transformations and xml stuff to both. In practice I think manually porting more practical.  If you have like 10 years worth of wpf common assets then you probably don't add loads to that regularly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Although it's not the answer I wanted, it's still the answer! I tend to export a lot of these icons from Metro Studio which seems to create the actual icons in a fairly cross-platform way. But that's fine - I won't waste time with trying to create a shareable library - I'll just have to update my PS scripts to create one lot specifically for WPF and the other for MAUI. Thanks again for the full answer.